# Horizontal Alignment of Multiple Item

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, itemize

How to align multiple nested itemize [image: Sample]

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}           

    \begin{document}

        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item-1
        \item Item-2

        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item-3
        \item Item-4

        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item-5
        \item Item-6

        \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your wish you will destroy deliberately designed forms of lists ...

Anyway, this you can obtain without nested lists:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item-1
        \item Item-2

        \item[--] Item-3
        \item[--] Item-4

        \item[*] Item-5
        \item[*] Item-6

    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I am using \usepackage{wasysym} and \item[\RHD]. However this way the bullets are not aligned properly. May you please help

Comment: Now I am using \usepackage{wasysym} and \item[\RHD]. However this way the bullets are not aligned properly. May you please help. Is it possible to use beamer bullet icons in latex {eg.http://i.stack.imgur.com/EVVaN.png}

Comment: The best way to help you that you ask new question where show how the `wasysym` symbols should be aligned. The same is for `beamer`.  In your new question you can add link to my answer.